# What is the lowest programming language to access hardware without using OS

Tags: programming-languages

i did some wiki and SO researches but i couldnt get the exact answer i look for. Thats why i asked this question.

(I did researches and didnt find an answer so dont downrate me because of this)

Firstly, title looks little weird. I will directly say my purpose. I was thinking of real life viruses. And told myself beat computer virus is most close to the real ones. I talked to a biology student and he said real viruses enters to cell,  sends the only DNA/RNA they have to the core and disable cell's deffence system. And then make the cell serve it and copy itselves.

(This was more like a biologic brief but i needed to tell this to  state myself best)

If we set a relation between real and computer viruses:
Cell- Computer
Virus- Virus
RNA/DNA- Code of virus
Core- OS
Deff system of cell- antivirus or firewall
Virus cloning itself- virus spreading to another computers

(Im stating again, i wrote all these to state my opinion. Otherwise i will be downrated for asking non-clear questions)

As you understood too, that virus should disable OS completely and give orders to hardware itself by its own ultra-simple OS

The languages i found out is

1-0 i guess this is called binary 
HE5J8EO guess this is raw or something 
And i dont remember the syntax but i think it was assembly, it is similar to programming languages but a very low one

While i cant code binary, i guess rest two or another language does what i want. If you know any, can you tell me what is its name?

Note: i am not a kid who doesnt know english grammar. Dont critisize me about this or suggest edits. English isnt my native language

Note: Virus development isnt my purpose, im trying to find the language i want. Virus case is just an example state what i am looking for exactly.

Reason of all these notes and explainations: I got -9 rating at my previous question and when i want to discuss the rule i got another -9 at meta because people didnt understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to do some work without an OS or any bare metal programming otherwise, assembly (sometimes assembler) is as low level as it gets. Assembly is in many ways more difficult to learn than a higher level language like C since the ASM language is not very feature rich (no one line loops, objects, functions in most cases). The other challenge you ight encounter if you are only familiar with higher language's is that there are many different assembly language's, one for each CPU architecture in fact. Unless you intend to be making nefarious software or an OS itself (which in many ways would be better served by something like C) you'd have to have a very clear intention and purpose to use an assembly language.

Comment: Since i do this research theorically and was inspired by cells and viruses, i dont actually mind coding and difficulty. However thanks for reminding.

My final question, think i coded an app with assembly. Which gives an order"print all screen to blue" to processor. How will i run this program? If i will double click a file with windows, will anyone ask for permission of accessing the screen? If it will be completely independent from OS, it should bypass all the security of computer and do its thing to computer?

Comment: Anything running within an OS (or attempted to be run) will be done at the discretion of the OS. I know running assembly applications in Windows is possible, I'm not entirely sure however if it can be done with completely native x86 ASM or if the program would need to make accommodations for working with Windows. That is where some more research will help, I do not work with assembly so I'd be interested to know if you find out.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic thing you could do on a "computer" would be sending codes directly to the processor. It's really hard if not impossible to do this on modern home computers because there are layers of hardware and software that manage that. I strongly suggest you research how 8-bit computers work, and how modern computers work. On modern computers the lowest level that can be programmed with a reasonable amount of difficulty is the kernel. Writing your own kernel would be essentially writing your own operating system. If you choose to take the route of writing your own kernel you'll have to manage all of the components of the computer which is very difficult.

In layman's terms, the processor is the point where software's logic is processed by mechanical means.

Comment: As i know before, 8 bit makes a byte. Is this related to it ?  Or 32 bit 64 bit operating systems?

Comment: Also, are the softwares you mention are assemblers and virtual machines (just like jvm)

Comment: "The number of bits in a processor refers to the size of the data types that it handles and the size of its registry. A 64-bit processor is capable of storing 264 computational values, including memory addresses, which means it's able to access over four billion times as much physical memory than a 32-bit processor!" quoted from quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-64-bit-and-32-bit

Comment: I had a small look to 8 bit computers and i understood what you mean a bit. Is there a language to manage  32 or 64 bit computers?

Comment: @Asaf31214 Machine Code or languages that compile into machine code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> If you know any, can you tell me what is its name?

VHDL is the lowest layer you can get in terms of programming language (since I was searching for a similar topic) and
That could be a point to start out:
https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-introduction-to-vhdl-for-beginners.html

I am actually working through "Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface 5ed that promise a good introduction in computer science and one of the benefits understanding the hardware and hardware coding/programming is getting a ~200% or more - faster and more efficient program with just adding about 22 lines of code in a c program to utelize parallel computing and matrix usage additionally to every compiler optimization.

So it is really worth working through it and learning deep.
I would revoke your -1 because your question makes sense - maybe a better example
than "hacking an os" might have given a better response as you discovered yourself - I just don't have enough points yet to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand that a virus is something that can spread from on computer to the other without any intervention of the creator.

Without a OS you won't have a medium to spread through.

If you want to give direct commands to the CPU with a OS on top, you can't!

As most of the popular OS will restrict such behaviour. Unless there is a bug/loophole in a OS and it's a ZERO day loophole, you won't have the privilege of a virus affecting many computers.